# FullCalendar usage with strings

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I have just today started looking at FullCalendar,and in the future i would like to use a php scritp to load events from a db, parse the results to be apt for FullCalendar, and call the $('#calendar').fullCalendar(options);
The thing is that if I call the function as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true}
                            );
```

All works ok, but if I call it like this:

```
 var stringCal="{
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true}";
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(

    stringCal

        );
```

It does not work, any ideas?
Thanks in beforehand, by the way im using FullCalendar 1.5.1

Answer (score 1):

If you have the object like a string then you can use the JSON.parse() function.

```
var stringCal = "{
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
    }";
```

then

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(JSON.parse(stringCal));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is an object literal but you have quotes around it.  This turns it into a string.  Remove the quotes like this:

```
var stringCal={
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true
};
```